# Issue with horizontal scrolling in TextField on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, material-ui, textfield

On my webpage, I have implemented a mui-TextField component with a certain width. When the content within the TextField exceeds its visible area, the expected behavior is to enable scrolling so that users can view and edit the entire content.

The scrolling functionality works as intended on desktop browsers and Android devices, allowing users to scroll through the TextField content by dragging the cursor. However, I have identified an issue when accessing the web page through a WebView on iPhones.

I have tried adding overflow-x property on my input TextField, It worked on Android but no impact on iPhone/iPad.

Thanks

I have tried adding overflow-x property on my input TextField, It worked on Android but no impact on iPhone/iPad.

I expect users to be able to scroll through the content of the mui-TextField in the iPhone WebView, similar to the behavior observed on other platforms.